# Finding patterns between two files

Tags: sed, awk, grep

`File1` contains a list of genes (represented by the letters). Each gene has been described by the protein it expresses (represented by the letters):

```
a-1
b-2
c-3
```

`File2` also contains a list of genes but each of them are repeated multiple times. Some of these genes are similar to that of `File1`:

```
a
a
a
b
b
c
c
c
```

I will need to find all the genes in `File1` that are common in `File2`. The common ones need to be printed into a third file (the multiple copies too). Along with that, the type of protein the genes express need to be written with it too (just like in `File1`).

How can I obtain the following `File3`?

```
a-1
a-1
a-1
b-2
b-2
c-3
c-3
c-3
```

Comment: You have to be more specific than that, you want all first parts of file 1 to be found in file 2 and then replaced with the whole entries of file 1?

Comment: @phk I want to find the items from file 1 in file 2. Once they are found, I want those items in file 2 to be appended with the corresponding values,that is, 1, 2, 3 etc.

Comment: You need to make some much better example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do that with gawk, which has a built-in variable `ARGIND`, the index in `ARGV` of the current file being processed.

We split each input line of the first file on the `-` and use the first field to index into an array `table` that stores the whole line. For the second file (and any following files), we use the whole line as the index into `table` to retrieve the desired line.

```
BEGIN{FS = "-"}
ARGIND==1{table[$1] = $0}
ARGIND>1{print table[$0]}
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS = "-"}; ARGIND==1{table[$1] = $0}; ARGIND>1{print table[$0]}' file_1 file_2
```

Here's another version that will work on traditional awk. It determines whether the current file is the first file by comparing `FNR`, the input record number in the current input file with `NR`, the total number of input records seen so far.

```
awk -F'-' 'NR==FNR{table[$1] = $0}; NR>FNR{print table[$0]}' file_1 file_2
```